# Drawing simple pointed annotations to number sections

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I would like to draw the following diagram on latex without diving into many low-level tikz commands and details. Is there any specific name for those types of diagrams? [This one](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/filesystem-tree/) looks fantastic example for me but it only shows a single component on the y axis. The code is quite easy to modify as well. So could you suggest to me any other example in order to handle this kinda graph?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest the use of `tikzmark` library, which is wonderful and versatile? (needs to be compile at least twice)

[image: pointed annotations to number sections]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.append style={inner xsep=1pt,inner ysep=3pt}}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily
    {\Huge \textbf{\tikzmarknode{a}{P}\,\tikzmarknode{b}{0}\,\tikzmarknode{c}{2}\,\tikzmarknode{d}{3 7}}}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>=Stealth,line width=1.5pt,blue]
        \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}
            \draw[blue] (\i.west) -- (\i.south west) -| (\i.east);
        
        \newcommand{\esp}{20pt}
            
        \draw[->] (a.south) |- ++ (5,-3) coordinate (P) node [right,black] {Position of P};
        \draw[->] (b.south) |- ([yshift=\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 0};
        \draw[->] (c.south) |- ([yshift=2*\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 2};
        \draw[->] (d.south) |- ([yshift=3*\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 37};
    \end{tikzpicture}           
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Since the desired picture should be inserted in a figure, it would be a better solution to create everything into a `tikzpicture`. Here's the code for that (I didn't insert the figure and caption to let you do it with your own parameters):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    
    \blindtext
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain=going right,
        node distance=1mm,
        every node/.style={
            inner xsep=1pt,
            inner ysep=3pt},
            font={\sffamily \bfseries \Huge}]

        \node[on chain] (a) {P};
        \node[on chain] (b) {0};
        \node[on chain] (c) {2};
        \node[on chain] (d) {3\,7};

        \begin{scope}[blue,line width=1.5pt,>=Stealth,every node/.style={font= \normalsize}]
            \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d}
                \draw[blue] (\i.west) -- (\i.south west) -| (\i.east);
            
            \newcommand{\esp}{20pt}
                
            \draw[->] (a.south) |- ++ (5,-3) coordinate (P) node [right,black] {Position of P};
            \draw[->] (b.south) |- ([yshift=\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 0};
            \draw[->] (c.south) |- ([yshift=2*\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 2};
            \draw[->] (d.south) |- ([yshift=3*\esp]P) node [right,black] {Position of 37};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \blindtext  
    
\end{document}
```

Leading to:

[image]

Comment: It looks fantastic. Only issue is that the tikz layer overlays on my current text body which should be just after this diagram. However, this diagram is placed over the text body. If I remove the overlay option on the tikzpicture, the structure of the diagram is broken. Any suggestion? Thanks @SebGlav

Comment: You can add vertical space underneath your P0237 to avoid this. Use `vspace*{3cm}` for example.

Comment: Yes, I know the vspace option for the vertical space but it is not really plausible. For instance, in that case I cannot arrange the caption of a figure (assume that tikzpicture inside a figure). For that reason, I was asked the previous question, is there a proper way to avoid the overlay ? Thanks again.

Comment: @ozturkib Use regular tikzpictures instead of tikzmark if you want a bounding box around everything. Basically, turn the tikzmarknodes into regular nodes and use the rest of the code as is without overlay.

Comment: @TeXnician I tried what you are saying like \node[a]{P}\,
                \node[b]{0}\,
                \node[c]{2}\,
                \node[d]{3 7} but it does not help :(

Comment: My bounding box looks like > \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.7\linewidth}{!}{
           \sffamily
            {\Huge 
             \textbf{
                \tikzmarknode{a}{P}\,
                \tikzmarknode{b}{0}\,
                \tikzmarknode{c}{2}\,
                \tikzmarknode{d}{3 7}
                }
            }

Comment: I'll edit my answer to let you choose between `tikzmark` and a complete `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Fantastic edit! Thanks a lot @SebGlav